# removing a file in unix

Tags: unix, io, filesystems, inode

In a UNIX filesystem, if the inode of the root directory is in the memory, what are the sequence of disk operations needed to remove a file in Desktop?

While I am trying to solve a question in textbook, I have seen this question but I could not solve it . Can anyone help me ?

If you know much about Unix, can you tell me what are sequence of disk operation needed for creating a file in Desktop ?

Comment: A file system consits of disk blocks. For removing a file four (maybe five) different *types* of disk blocks are involved. 1) Name them. Now for every type 2) write out the operations that are needed. 3) now, try to invent the correct order.

Answer (score 3):

Use `rm` to *remove* files in Unix. e.g.,

```
rm file_to_delete
```

or better yet if you are uncertain about working in Unix

```
rm -i file_to_delete
```

which will prompt with the name of the file to be deleted to confirm the operation.

The `file_to_delete` can be in the current directory, or in some other directory as long as the path is properly specified.

See [rm man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?rm) for more information.

As for *creating* a file, you can create an empty file with the `touch` command. I.e.,

```
touch some_file
```

will create an empty file named `some_file`. Again, this can be in the current directory, or any directory with the path specified.

For more information see the [touch man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?touch).

Your questions wasn't quite clear to me, so if this doesn't answer it please add a comment or (better yet) consider possibly rephrasing your original question or at least the title of your question (*removing a file in unix*)

Comment: downvote without any explanation doesn't help anyone ..

Comment: I agree it's not fair to down vote an answer without a comment.

Comment: @fatai .. rather than saying about my answer "it sucks" can you tell me how this answer could be improved or *how it doesn't answer "removing a file in unix"*? That would be much more helpful.

Comment: +1, downvoting a correct answer is unfair.

Comment: It is a correct answer to a different question.

Comment: We have already wasted too much time. It is homework anyway, and the OP is too lazy to react. And the title does not cover the body of the question.